# reuse the same rules for building different targets

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm developing a project that includes multiple static libraries. The way in which I build them is always the same. I would like to know how I can reuse these rules for all the libraries and avoid doing copy & paste for each one. Here is an example for building a 'foo' library.

```
# inputs
#
FOO_LIB_NAME  := libfoo.a
FOO_SRC_DIR   := $(SRC_DIR)/foo
FOO_SRC_FILES := \
        foo_file1.cc                              \
        subdir/foo_file2.cc                       \
        subdir/foo_file3.cc                       \
        ...
FOO_CFLAGS    :=

# rules
#
FOO_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix $(FOO_SRC_DIR)/,$(FOO_SRC_FILES))
FOO_OBJ_FILES := $(subst .cc,.o,$(FOO_SRC_FILES))

$(FOO_LIB_NAME): $(FOO_OBJ_FILES)
        $(AR) rc $@ $^

$(FOO_OBJ_FILES): %.o: %.cc
        $(CXX) $(COMMON_CFLAGS) $(FOO_CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Additionally, if you have any comment about the previous excerpt of code I would be glad to know about it. I'm quite new at writing Makefiles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried `include makefile.common`

Comment: Hi deebee, could you give me an example using a common makefile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid duplicating GNU Make rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149989/avoid-duplicating-gnu-make-rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with templates and the `eval` function in Make.  The [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) has examples in [the section on `eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function)

Here is the example from the manual:

```
PROGRAMS    = server client

server_OBJS = server.o server_priv.o server_access.o
server_LIBS = priv protocol

client_OBJS = client.o client_api.o client_mem.o
client_LIBS = protocol

# Everything after this is generic

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAMS)

define PROGRAM_template =
 $(1): $$($(1)_OBJS) $$($(1)_LIBS:%=-l%)
 ALL_OBJS   += $$($(1)_OBJS)
endef

$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))

$(PROGRAMS):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(ALL_OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the structure I was looking for :)